# Ошибка RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache
def F(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n > 1:
        return F(n-1) + 10 * G(n-1) + 15 * n
@lru_cache    
def G(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n > 1:
        return F(n-1) - 2 * G(n-1)
print(G(675))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
File "<string>", line 13, in G
  File "<string>", line 7, in F
  File "<string>", line 7, in F
  File "<string>", line 7, in F
  [Previous line repeated 495 more times]
  File "<string>", line 4, in F
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
>
```

если убрать @lru_cache ошибку вроде не выдает, но слишком долго работает (работает вообще?)

Comment: 675 - слишком большое число. Попробуй уменьшить его

Comment: к сожалению, прикол в том, что мне нужно именно 675, я и так попытался оптимизировать его через lru_cache (вероятно, неправильно), но это вообще не помогло

Comment: вероятнее всего проблема в мемоизации сверху. Попробуй в цикле вычислить все значения начиная с 1 до 675

Comment: спасибо, но заработал, неправильно, но хоть что-то

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что неправильно?

Comment: вообще все шикарно, спасибо, я просто условие задачи не дочитал, все правильно

Comment: попробуй выполнить у себя `import sys; 
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())` - что выведет?